# Learning sum of a function using Keras

Tags: neural-network, keras

I am fitting a function $y:R^3\to R$ using the following model in Keras.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=3, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear', kernel_initializer='normal'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=8)
predictions = model.predict(x_test)
```

To train, I used a data set consisting of $\{\mathbf{x}_i\}_{i=1}^N$ and $\{y_i\}_{i=1}^N$. This worked as expected.

Now imagine a slightly different situation where for each sample $i$ I have a pair of $\mathbf{x}_{i,1}$ and $\mathbf{x}_{i,2}$ ($\mathbf{x}_{i,\alpha} \in R^3$) and my target data point corresponding to $i$ is modelled as $y_i=z(\mathbf{x}_{i,1})+z(\mathbf{x}_{i,2})$, with $z:R^3 \to R$. Is it possible to define such a model in Keras, and how to do it? If not Keras, any other framework?

Answer (score 1):

If you had two different functions $z_1$ and $z_2$, I would agree with Piotr: you could have two parallel networks, one for each part of the input, that join together at the end.  This would minimize (though not eliminate) information from $x_{i,1}$ bleeding into the fitting of $z_2$.

But with $z_1=z_2=z$, we'd like to enforce that those two parallel networks are the same.  The idea of using the same weights for different parts of the input remind of convolutions, and I think that will work here: let $x_{i,1},x_{i,2}$ be the columns of a $3\times 2$ input, apply 1-dimensional width-1 convolutional layers instead of dense ones, and add a "Sum Pooling" layer at the end.  (Without writing something custom, you could manage that in Keras with average pooling and manually deal with the factor of 2.)

Comment: Thanks for this. I sort of understand and see in principle how it should work. In practice I will need to play around with this a bit...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need `functional` model instead of `sequential`. Read more [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional).